# property is undefined even if it is defined in class

Tags: typescript

I have trouble calling just a single property from my class.
Did I do mapping wrong? Thing is that map a new array with QuizWord objects and my mapping works great. But I have properties and methods inside the class that I want to call later on which should go with the object. But they don't. How come? I thought I defined new objects when mapping them.

It started with me want to use a simple foreach loop and loop through the objects and calling a method to add things to the object, but I can't call any methods.

Below is some of my code.

```
let list: Array<QuizWord> = words.map((a) => {
    return <QuizWord>({
        name: a.name
    });
});

let letstrythisinstead: QuizWord = new QuizWord();
console.log(letstrythisinstead.test2); // this is not undefined. it works! 

list.forEach((q: QuizWord) => {
    console.log(q.name); // prints name correctly after mapping above
    console.log(q.test2) // is undefined. why? I have defined it in my class..
});

export class QuizWord {
    public test2: string = "hi";
    public name: string;
}
```

Comment: Your mapping HOF doesn't return an instance of QuizWord, it returns a POJO you're *casting* to QuizWord, and it has no `test2` property, only a name.

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you now I understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code here

```
    return <QuizWord>({
        name: a.name
    });
```

doesn't transform the returned data to `QuizWord`. It just tells Typescript that it is a `Quizword` item, and in this case, it is not true.

Basically, `QuizWord` is a class, so to assign a value, you need to construct it.
You can implement it like this

```
export class QuizWord {
    public test2: string = "hi";

    constructor(
        public name: string,
    ){ }
}
```

and

```
    return new QuizWord(a.name);
```

instead of

```
    return <QuizWord>({
        name: a.name
    });
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now I understand. Too bad you can't define properties within brackets and must use the constructor but it's no problem.

Comment: Yes, you can't, because the brackets define the type, not construct the class. Assignment happen in the constructor, not in the type definition (maybe it will change later) :D. Should we mark this as done?

Comment: Ahh I see. We will:)